# How to add row field after column field in telerik reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, reporting

I am creating a report in telerik reporting. Structure of the report:

[image]

*Name* and *day* are row and column fields respectively. Now I want to add a row field after the column field. How to do that? I am using Cross Tab control.

Comment: Please post more information, preferably in an image to get a better understanding of your question.

Comment: @novice_dev, Image is already there.